# Calculating value of n

Tags: inequality, polynomials, radicals, factoring

I have this Inequality

> $$\displaystyle (n)^{\frac{1}{3}}-(n-1)^\frac{1}{3} \lt \frac{1}{12}$$

I want to calculate the value of **n** as I have done some calculation I think finding the absolute value is not possible or may be it is possible, I have done some calculation but those calculation does not align with any mathematical concept,   I would love to know this particular question belong to which concept of mathematics.
Thanks in advance

Comment: $$12<n^{2/3}-n^{1/3}(n-1)^{1/3}+(n-1)^{2/3}<2n^{2/3}$$

Comment: Are you sure you do not want to find the least $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ such that $$\sqrt[3]{n}\color{red}{-}\sqrt[3]{n-1}<\frac{1}{12}$$ holds? Please add some actual attempt, "*those calculation do not align with any mathematical concept*" makes no sense.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio yes exactly, and regarding the actual attempt , i did some attempt but i dont know how to put it into word .

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  i dont understand why you changed the sign from plus to minus .

Comment: @TaleevAalam: the problem with the $+$ sign is really trivial since the LHS is an increasing function of $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the following identity.
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)$$ and since
$$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2=0$$ for $a=b=c$ only and $\sqrt[3]{n}\neq-\sqrt[3]{n-1}$, our inequality is equivalent to
$$n-(n-1)-\frac{1}{12^3}-3\cdot\frac{1}{12}\sqrt[3]{n(n-1)}<0$$ or
$$\sqrt[3]{n^2-n}>4-\frac{1}{432},$$
which gives $n\geq8.508...$ and we have $n\geq9$ in the natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the continuous function
$$
f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[3]{x-1}
$$
over $[1,\infty)$. We have $f(1)=1$; moreover, for $x>1$,
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{x^2}}-\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}}=
\frac{\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}-\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{3\sqrt[3]{x^2(x-1)^2}}
$$
which is obviously negative over $(1,\infty)$, so the function is decreasing.

Now we have
$$
f(8)=\sqrt[3]{8}-\sqrt[3]{7}=2-\sqrt[3]{7}
$$
and $2-\sqrt[3]{7}>1/12$, because $23^3=12167>7\cdot 12^3=12096$. Also
$$
f(9)=\sqrt[3]{9}-\sqrt[3]{8}=\sqrt[3]{9}-2
$$
and $\sqrt[3]{9}-2<1/12$ because $9\cdot 12^3=15552<25^3=15625$.

A pocket calculator is thus sufficient to conclude that the inequality is satisfied by the integers $n\ge 9$.

Why $8$ and $9$? A pocket calculator will show that
\begin{align}
f(1)-1/12&=11/12\\
f(2)-1/12&\approx0.177\\
f(3)-1/12&\approx0.099\\
f(4)-1/12&\approx0.062\\
f(5)-1/12&\approx0.039\\
f(6)-1/12&\approx0.024\\
f(7)-1/12&\approx0.012\\
f(8)-1/12&\approx0.004\\
f(9)-1/12&\approx-0.003
\end{align}
so we know that the root of $f(x)=1/12$ is between $8$ and $9$, but computations with integers are safer than using calculators with floating point operations.

---

The other inequality $\sqrt[3]{n}+\sqrt[3]{n-1}<1/12$ is easy as well. The derivative of the associated function is positive on $(0,\infty)$ (except again at $1$), so the function is increasing. Since $\sqrt[3]{0}+\sqrt{0-1}<1/12$ and $\sqrt[3]{1}+\sqrt[3]{1-1}=1>1/12$, the inequality holds only for $n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

1. The function is decreasing if $n\geq1$:

$\begin{align}
f(n+1)-f(n)=\\
(n+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}+(n-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}
-2n^{\frac{1}{3}}=\\
n^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-2\right)\leq\\
n^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{3n}\right)+\left(1-\frac{1}{3n}\right)-2\right)=0
\end{align}$

2. $g(x):=f(x)-\frac{1}{12}=0 \iff x\sim8.5$
3. Thus, we have $n\geq 9$